# Insert Timeslot In mysql Table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a system using PHP and MySQL.
One of my *form* would prompt the user to fill-up two *textbox* namely `startTime` and `endTime`. User must fill-up both text box and when submitted, insert them into my table named `Slot` and output them along with the previous data.

```
 5:30  
 6:00
 6:30
 7:00
 7:30
 8:00
```

How can I do it? Guide me along your answer.
Here's my code:

```
$i=0;
$sid=1;
$appointmentsdate=$_REQUEST['sTime'];   
$appointmentedate=$_REQUEST['eTime'];

for($appointmentsdate;$appointmentsdate<$appointmentedate;$appointmentsdate++)
{
    $arrayStartTime[$i]="{$appointmentsdate}:00";
    $i++;
    $arrayStartTime[$i]="{$appointmentsdate}:30";
    $i++;
}
echo "<pre>";       
print_r($arrayStartTime);
die;

for ($k=0; $k<sizeof($arrayStartTime); $k++) 
{
    SJB_DB::query('insert into `schedule_slot` (`schedule_id`,`startTime`,`endTime`) values  
            (?s,?s,?s)',$sid,$arrayStartTime[$k],$arrayStartTime[$k+1]);    
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
#your inputs
$start = "11:00"; 
$time_end = "13:30";

#converting them to timestamps
$time_start = strtotime($start);
$time_end = strtotime($time_end);

#looping
while($time_start <= $time_end){
  $someArr[] = date("H:i",$time_start)."\n";
  $time_start = strtotime('+30 minutes',$time_start);
}
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/hdeXqn65)

---

Integrating it into your current code, it should look like (untested):

```
$i=0;
$sid=1;

$appointmentsTimeStart = strtotime($_REQUEST['sTime']);
$appointmentsTimeEnd = strtotime($_REQUEST['sTime']);

for($appointmentsTimeStart; $appointmentsTimeStart<$appointmentsTimeEnd; $appointmentsdate1++)
{    
    $arrayStartTime[$i] = date("H:i", $appointmentsTimeStart);
    $appointmentsTimeStart = strtotime('+30 minutes',$appointmentsTimeStart);    
    $i++;    
}

print_r($arrayStartTime);
```

Comment: Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. on line 6

Comment: @kapil: That error is pretty self-explanatory. Use the `date_default_timezone_set()` function to set the default time-zone.